# How to correctly exclude slf4j-jdk14 when using slfj-log4j12?

Tags: log4j, ivy, slf4j

I am using Ivy for dependency management in my project. I want to use *SLF4J* for logging. I added

```
<dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.7.5" />
```

And it downloads both *slf4j-log4j12* and *slf4j-jdk14*, which cause a binding conflict. I tried to exclude it by using

```
<dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.7.5">
  <exclude module="slf4j-jdk14" />
</dependency>
```

But the module is still downloaded. I have put the **exclude** tag directly under the **dependencies** tag to exclude this module. Why?

Comment: slf4j-jdk14 is not a dependency of slf4j-log4j12. I suspect that some other dependency is pulling in slf4j-jdk14.

Comment: i had that idea too. but not sure. thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried running 'ant report' to get the Ivy report and seeing what, under the section "Dependencies Overview", is causing slf4j-jdk14 is be downloaded? It should tell you what the dependency is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way to solve this problem is to create a global exclude:

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency ..
   <dependency ..
   <dependency ..

   <exclude org="org.slf4j" module="slf4j-jdk14"/>
</dependencies>
```

To discover where transitive dependencies come from, I recommend always generating an ivy report:

```
<target name="resolve" description="Resolve dependencies using ivy">
    <ivy:resolve/>
    <ivy:report todir="${build.dir}/ivy-report" graph="false"/>
</target>
```

Comment: thanks. unfortunately, I am using the IvyIDE plugin for Eclipse. I do not know how to generate a report from it. Do you have any idea?